# Force Swagger to expose details of Request Object

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, swagger, spring-restcontroller

I am creating a Rest Service using Spring boot and for documentation I am using Swagger(via SpringFox). And it is almost working fine. The issue arises when I moved all of my query parameters to a request object and used that in the method signature thus implicitly binding the values and getting spring validators fired implicitly.

This is how my method signature looks:

```
public List<Category> getCategory( @Valid CategoryInputRequest inputRequest) throws JsonParseException,
  JsonMappingException, IOException
```

The CategoryInputRequest is a bean having a plain bean structure:

```
@ApiModel(value = "Input Description")
public class CategoryInputRequest  {
   @NotNull(message="SE Number is mandatory")
   @Size(min=10,max=10,message="SE Number must have 10 characters")
   @ApiModelProperty
   private String idNumber;

   @NotNull(message="Platform ID is mandatory")
   @ApiModelProperty
   private String platformId;
   .
   .
   .
```

Where IdNumber, platformId are the query parameters and data validation and binding happens flawlessly. But Swagger assumes  "CategoryInputRequest inputRequest" in the method signature to be a requestBody type of parameter and not query pameters and hence doesn't expose the individual fields to the user. Instead gives a big text area to put a JSON block in. I tried giving @APIModelProperty but it doesn't work.

Can anyone please help? I hope I was able to explain the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question:

public List getCategory( @Valid CategoryInputRequest inputRequest) works but the proper declaration should have the keywork @ModelAttribute.This indicates that the mapping is being done from the query paramters in url and not the request body. And swagger is able to analyze the pattern correctly. Hope it helps someone :)